# Xamarin UI Test sometimes fails to start

Tags: xamarin, testing, visual-studio-mac

Times from times when we try to run our Xamarin UI Tests our app/test fails to start with the following error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request
  ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket has been shut down.
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : The socket has been shut down
```

What is happening? Here is my environment:

- MacOS High Sierra
- Visual Studio for Mac 7.6.1 (Build 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes during IDE updates, even Mono can be updated. It seems, from my experience, that the version `5.10.1.17` is the most reliable for UI Testing and `5.12.x` doesn't even works. So if you are having this sort of problem, try to downgrade your Mono version.

You may need to reinstall everything up, depending on how much of a mess is your environment.

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

1. Don't get the latest version of the Visual Studio.
2. Install version 5.10.1 of the Mono package :  https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/
3. Before install, close Visual Studio then proceeds with the downloaded package installation.
4. Restart Visual Studio and go to Preferences->Project->.NET Runtime and select the 5.10.1 version of Mono as the default one.
5. After that reload Visual Studio and everything should work.

Cheers!

Comment: @TMob Cool. Thanks :)

Comment: Wow. It's really disturbing that we can't upgrade to the "latest & greatest" without breaking our automated tests. Are we supposed to never upgrade?

Comment: @iupchris10 May be now the latest version works with VS2019. I haven't tried it but let me know if you it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem persists and you are on Mac, you may need to do a complete clean up in the Environment on the system modified by the Visual Studio Installer (Library/Framework folder) before installing again.

Follow [these guidelines](https://superuser.com/questions/1149129/how-to-completely-remove-visual-studio-from-mac) to truly uninstall Visual Studio (and its dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

Please update your xamarin UI test package after updating your visual studio that will resolve your problem